# Can´t knit Rmarkdown file; Incomplete string?

Tags: r, string, r-markdown, knitr, gt

I´ve been trying to knit my RMarkdown file. But unfortunately I always receive this error message

> Quitting from lines 22-23 (RM_fucku.Rmd)
> error in source("tbl_summary_RMarkdown.R") :
> tbl_summary_RMarkdown.R:9:3: unexpected INCOMPLETE_STRING
> 23:
> 24: tab4_5
> ^
> Calls:  ... withVisible -> eval_with_user_handlers -> eval -> eval -> source
> Execution halted

The error message refers to my Rscript in which I have saved the code for my summary table:

```
tab4_5 <- students %>% 
  select(cob, sex, relationship, age, term, lifesat, job, faculty) %>%
  tbl_summary(
    missing = "no",
    by = c("faculty"),
    type = all_continuous() ~ "continuous2",
    statistic = all_continuous() ~ c("{mean}", "{min}", "{max}"),
    label = list(
      cob ~ "Country of birth",
      sex ~ "Sex",
      relationship ~ "Relationship status",
      age ~ "Age (in years)",
      term ~ "# of terms",
      lifesat ~ "Life satisfaction",
      job ~ "Paid part-time job"))


tab4_5
```

I´m using R.4.2.1. on an windows 10.
I have loaded the packages and a dataset separately. The Incomplete string issue is not new to me. I sometimes receive a similar error message when I try to install and load Packages.
Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you passing in a dataframe before `select()`?

Comment: yes I have, sry that wasn´t visible before but I´ve just edited my post. You should now see the whole thing

Comment: Can you run that code outside of r-markdown?

Comment: yes, I can run it without error messages. That is the strange thing.

Comment: Is your Rmd file in the same location as your Rproj file? Rmd files when knit treat the directory they are saved in as their home folder, and that may be different from the folder that you use in, say, R scripts for your project directory. That's a common cause of frustration when knitting Rmd files.

Comment: Your remark that the "incomplete string issue" is not new to you made me think and look through your previous questions. In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73066868/2706569) the path to your working directory contains the character "ä". Is this also the case with your current problem? Can you move the project to a directory without any special characters in its path?